# multiboot header moving entry point

Tags: gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, kernel

Originally x64 vmlinux entry point is:

```
Entry point address:               0x1000000
```

I define the Multiboot header to be in a seperate section, then link that section at the start of .text in the linker script.
after this entry point is:

```
Entry point address:               0x1000010
```

With old entry address i am able to jump from my bootloader to the kernel entry point and it is successfully booting, however I want my vmlinux to be multiboot complaint (so i need that header)
but after adding it and perform jump to the new address, it's hanging..

Is the jump address incorrect or I need to change something in kernel ?
--- a/arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S
+++ b/arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S

```
+.section .mboot
+.code64
+   /* Align 32 bits boundary.  */
+   .align  8
+   /* Multiboot header.  */
+multiboot_header:
+   /* magic */
+   .long   MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC
+   /* flags */
+   .long   MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS
+   /* checksum */
+   .long   -(MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC + MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS)

.text
__HEAD
.code64
.globl startup_64
startup_64:
```

--- a/arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S
+++ b/arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S

```
@@ -91,6 +91,7 @@ SECTIONS
/* Text and read-only data */
    .text :  AT(ADDR(.text) - LOAD_OFFSET) {
+       *(.mboot)
    _text = .;
    /* bootstrapping code */
    HEAD_TEXT
```

objdump -d

```
Disassembly of section .text:

ffffffff81000000 <multiboot_header>:
ffffffff81000000:       02 b0 ad 1b 03 00       add    0x31bad(%rax),%dh
ffffffff81000006:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
ffffffff81000008:       fb                      sti
ffffffff81000009:       4f 52                   rex.WRXB push %r10
ffffffff8100000b:       e4 90                   in     $0x90,%al

ffffffff8100000c <_text>:
ffffffff8100000c:       90                      nop
ffffffff8100000d:       90                      nop
ffffffff8100000e:       90                      nop
ffffffff8100000f:       90                      nop

ffffffff81000010 <startup_64>:
ffffffff81000010:       e8 a4 01 00 00          callq  ffffffff810001b9 <verify_cpu>
ffffffff81000015:       48 8d 2d f0 ff ff ff    lea    -0x10(%rip),%rbp        # 
ffffffff8100000c <_text>
ffffffff8100001c:       48 81 ed 0c 00 00 01    sub    $0x100000c,%rbp
ffffffff81000023:       48 89 e8                mov    %rbp,%rax
ffffffff81000026:       25 ff ff 1f 00          and    $0x1fffff,%eax
```

System.map:

```
0000000001000010 A phys_startup_64
ffffffff81000000 t multiboot_header
ffffffff8100000c T _text
ffffffff81000010 T startup_64
```

Comment: This question is hard to answer without seeing more of your code. Could you provide us with more background information?

Comment: It's hard to believe the initial jump hangs. Did you debug it to find out, where exactly it hangs and why? Maybe it jumps to completely wrong address? Or your kernel is loaded elsewhere, or it is damaged by your previous code, or not loaded at all due to some bug, etc... As long as you jump to some address, the CPU will execute machine code which is stored there (either yours, or random content of memory left there after power-on or other code). It can hardly "hang" (except special situations like `cli` `hlt` intentional "freeze" of CPU). If it executes, it does *something*. See in debugger.

Comment: I have provided more info in the post. It is jumping to the correct address (0x1000010) I have check it. Without a header it is jumping to 0x1000000 and simply booting

Comment: Wonder if it is related to the fact that the VMA starts at ffffffff81000000. Seem to recall a GRUB2 patch for 64-bit kernels to give them proper support for higher half VMAs. What version of grub are you booting with?

Comment: https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/2/15/347

Comment: Current grub implementaion thinks the entry address should be a VA. E.g. for 64 bit kernel, the entry address (0x1000000) is actually phiscial address. I am not using GRUB2, I am using bootloader written from scratch.